# Convert object to a queryable

Tags: c#, linq, object, iqueryable

I used a modified version of this answer: [How to dynamically create a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp) to create a dynamic object that represents a typed class.

```
public static object CreateNewObject(string[] columnNames)
{
    var myType = CompileResultType(columnNames);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(myType) as IQueryable;

}
```

Then in the main app:

```
var obj = MyTypeBuilder.CreateNewObject(rs.ColumnNames);
```

I need to somehow convert that to an `IQueryable` so I can do some Linq calls off it, such as `.where()`, `.select()` ect. Naturally, I am not currently able to because my app doesn't know what is exactly in that object, or what that object is.

So what I need is:

```
var obj = MyTypeBuilder.CreateNewObject(rs.ColumnNames);
List<obj> aListICanFill = new List<obj>();

..

aListICanFill.where(x => x.Equals("")).take(3);
```

I've blindly tried different casts, and even failed to try an iterate through the object - and now I'm completley stuck.

Is there any way to do this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx seems to be something I should hook onto.
What my object looks like:

[image]

Comment: What syntax exactly do you need? {array of your objects}.Select(...) or {your object}.Select(...) ?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `IQueryable` on your class? Or maybe what you really want is a `List<MyClass>` that you can do `.Where()` on?

Comment: So this object will be my class - something like `List<thisObject>` would be the best case scenario.

Comment: @RufusL it returns as an object though, not a class...

Comment: @SemiDemented if you want this, an anonymous class is NOT the way you should go. Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface However, you can make a List of Objects `List<Object>`

Comment: @RoyalBg I really do need to create this class dynamically though...

Comment: Them you can try with `List<Object>` but you will have hard time invoking properties from the object while querying ...

Comment: Can you use a List<dynamic>? Then you can use Where and Select Linq methods. `var items = new List<dynamic>()
{
   new { Name = "A", Age = 10 },
   new { Name = "B", Age = 20 },
   new { Name = "C", Age = 30 },
};

items.Where(item => item.Age > 20).Dump();`

Comment: @Shane Sorry for the ignorance, but how could I use the object in a dynamic list? Could you maybe provide more info in an answer?

Comment: @Shane I feel that the same issue with the types will have here after querying the collection. One cannot explicitly invoke `item.Name` while iterating through the List for example. Oh, I now saw the whole comment. Is that really possible in the `Where`, because I think it will not let you call `Age`, but I don't have anywhere to test it now

Answer (score 2):

If you can use List<dynamic> you can use Where and Select IEnumerable<T> extension methods like below. This does not work with IQueryable because those methods require an Expression which cannot be dynamic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DynamicListTest
{
   internal class Program
   {
      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var dynamicObjects = GetDynamicObjects().Cast<dynamic>().AsEnumerable();

         var itemsToPrint = dynamicObjects
            .Where(item => item.Age > 30);

         foreach (var item in itemsToPrint)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
         }

         Console.ReadKey();
      }

      private static IQueryable GetDynamicObjects()
      {
         return new List<dynamic>()
         {
            new { Name = "A", Age = 10 },
            new { Name = "B", Age = 20 },
            new { Name = "C", Age = 30 },
            new { Name = "D", Age = 40 },
            new { Name = "E", Age = 50 },
         }.AsQueryable();
      }
   }
}
```

This prints

{ Name = D, Age = 40 }

{ Name = E, Age = 50 }

Comment: In my case, `GetDynamicObjects` returns an object dynamically filled, not a convenient List<T>. This will work if I could convert the object to a List<T>, which I was originally trying to do.

Comment: @SemiDemented Oh OK it helps seeing the code. I have edited my answer to use an IQueryable as the source data, does this help you? Note that it has to be converted to IEnumerable first.

Answer (score 0):

check out linq to objects

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx

Hopefully your object contains an array?

Could you give a sample of how you want to query it?  And also what CompileResultType does?

```
var myType = CompileResultType(columnNames);
```

EDIT

For future reference - as suggested by Shane - OP is trying out - Dynamic Linq dynamiclinq.codeplex.com

Comment: I've updated my Q with what my object looks like - so something like `myType.Where(x => x.CompanyName == "Test").Take(3);`

Comment: ok try something like this     --                                return ((IEnumerable)Activator.CreateInstance(myType)).AsQueryable();

Comment: Remember this is just the names for a dynamic class - there is no data yet... However I get this error: `Unable to cast object of type 'MyDynamic' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.`

Comment: try using an ExpandoObject -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx            sample - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747058/is-it-possible-to-query-list-of-expandoobject

Comment: That seems to have very specific types - I can't see how I will be able to create an ExpandoObject without knowing what I want.

Comment: ExpandoObject allows you to add/remove properties add runtime - all dynamically - your linq will run but not be type safe    -- to clarify your problem - are you trying to create a dynamic object from given column names?  With values stored against these column keys?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64158/discussion-between-semidemented-and-chris-mckelt).

Comment: For future reference - as suggested by Shane - OP is trying out - Dynamic Linq http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/